# "Prolers" is in no English dictionary and yet it's in several online Scrabble dictionaries. Is it an English word?

Tags: meaning, is-it-a-word

Is the word *prolers* an English word or just rubbish/noise added to the Scrabble dictionary?

If it's a real English word, what does it mean?

(Not a general reference question by virtue of this word not being in the OED, Merriam-Webster, or any other English dictionary I could find.)

Comment: "prolers" is not in the scrabble dictionary according to http://www.hasbro.com/scrabble/en_US/search.cfm.

Comment: Okay, it is in an online Scrabble dictionary for several Scrabble games including the Scrabble-brand game for Android, but is NOT valid as a regular table-boardgame Scrabble word?  So then it's a "noise word" in certain things like Words With Friends ,and the official Android Scrabble (TM) app, but it has no english meaning.

Comment: What exactly is a proler?

Comment: It's clearly a blend of *prole* and *prowler*. So a worker-thief. (-:

Comment: PROLERS is not in the _Official Scrabble Players Dictionary,_ the Scrabble _Tournament Word List,_ or the Words with Friends dictionary, so I'm not sure why your apps are accepting it. Bug, maybe? Or is this just showing up in some online dictionary somewhere? Could you please link to it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a spurious entry in a game dictionary, not an English word.

Comment: @BraddSzonye: The word is in the OED and two Chambers dictionaries. Those apps probably aren't official Scrabble games or are spin-offs, and probably use non-official Scrabble word lists too. See my [answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/129962/9001).

Comment: It's accepted by the official Scrabble app on android. Which is weird because they use the scrabble trademark but obviously do not use the official scrabble dictionary.

Comment: Today the word seems to survive only in proper names.

Comment: [If you use the word when speaking English, then it is an English word.](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/1991/300)

Comment: Zerg flibble derp niffle wingo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Proler* is a real English word, but one that's not used any more. Whether it's accepted in Scrabble or Words with Friends or other word games is up to their official word lists.

It has no individual entry in *OED* online, but *proler[s]* appears in three 17th and 18th century quotations under *prowler*.

Searching Google Books, it can be found in *[The Chambers Dictionary](http://books.google.com/books?id=pz2ORay2HWoC&pg=RA2-PA1315&dq=%22proler%22%20dictionary&hl=en&sa=X&ei=DVtOUvPLPJGK4gSQ5YHIDg&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAg)* (Page 1315, 1998):

> **prole2, proler** Obsolete forms of **prowl** and **prowler**.

It also shows up in *[The Chambers Crossword Dictionary, 3rd edition](http://books.google.com/books?id=WvWFUfpuxCQC&pg=RA11-PA96&dq=%22proler%22%20OR%20%22prolers%22%20dictionary&hl=en&sa=X&ei=sltOUsbvFamJ4gSv_YCQDg&ved=0CJQBEOgBMBI)* (Page 96, 201
2):

> **prowler**
>
> 06 patrol, proler, roamer 07 proller, prouler, stalker 08 tenebrio 09 nighthawk, scavenger

From there it's a short hop over to other (unofficial) Scrabble dictionaries.

Answer (score 3):

From the OED (1928), page 1447, second entry in second column of my photo-reduced edition:

> **Proler** obs. form of *prowler*.

Comment: It has no entry in OED online, but *proler[s]* appears in three 17th and 18th century quotations for *prowler*.

Comment: @Hugo: I missed it initially, tucked in between two larger entries. Are you sure it isn't there? I never heard of the OED losing words before.

Comment: It's not there in thre alphabetic listing, but it's an electronic website so you can search using a computer. I don't think they've lost *proler* but rather merged its quotations under the *prowler* entry.