# Is there such a word as "intriguement?"

Tags: is-it-a-word

I have heard a couple of people use *intriguement* casually but there is nothing online except for a listing in the *[Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=intriguement)*:

> **intriguement**
>
> the feeling of being intrigued 
> *He was nearly as old as her father, much to Martha's intriguement.*

So, is it an actual word?

Comment: How would it be different from the noun **intrigue**?

Comment: A bit like awesomeness instead of awe.

Comment: What does "actual word" mean? If some people use it, and other people understand it, that makes it a word. There's no authority for the English language that decrees what is or isn't valid.

Comment: I'm not sure that the first answer to  https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/215998/can-one-ever-say-for-certain-a-word-does-not-exist is the last word on wordhoodness but I think it touches most of the sides of the box.

Comment: @Tim  *Intrigue* (noun) refers to something like a secret conspiracy or love affair, or the practice of doing such things, rather than the state of being intrigued. So intrigue is different to intriguement, and even if you don't like that coinage such a word might seem necessary (intriguedness might also work).

Comment: @TimR: replace the 'b' in your chosen example words with an 'm' and the sentence makes complete sense and doesn't stretch the language at all. I conclude therefore, that yes indeed, someone who has been *abused* is in a state of *abusement* 

Answer (score 1):

The word *intriguement* is not a dictionary or a standard word. It can be considered a neologism or a nonce word modelled on established words like *excitement, astonishment, amazement* and that has been used by some people for the intended meaning, as the noun *intrigue* doesn't have the sense "the condition or feeling of being intrigued".

For example, *intrigueness* is another neologized word you can find in Google Books. Although, it is better to use established words for the intended meaning; perhaps *fascination* fits the bill.

*[OED](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/fascination_n?tab=meaning_and_use#4790924)* definition of *fascination*:

> The state of being enthralled or intrigued by, or extremely interested in, something or someone. 
> <sub>Now the usual sense.</sub>

Comment: I've not come across the 'now the usual sense' caveat (or anti-caveat) before; it's very helpful. // I take it that by 'not a dictionary word' you include an OED non-show.